# Wireless ADB over mobile data connection Android

Tags: android, adb

Apologies if there is a better way of categorising this or explaining more detailed what I need help with.

I've been reading up and trying to find a way of connecting to adb without WiFi. I was looking to see if there's any way of having the phone host a hotspot to connect to in order to allow me to turn on wireless ADB on the host device?
Does anyone else have any solutions of using wireless ADB outside of terrestrial WiFi?

Sorry if this isn't well enough explained, if any one has any questions that can help me clarify what I'm looking for that would be great?
Thank you all very much for any help
P

I'm not sure what else to write?

Comment: I was using this on WiFi https://github.com/tytydraco/LADB

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/294760511

Comment: Please keep in mind that adb is to my knowledge a plain text protocol, so using adb over the internet is like using http without TLS or telnet, giving bad people an easy way to attack your phone and e.g. installing malware.

Comment: Yeah, Shizuku needs adb command every boot to work